# Split a Text string based on 2 delimiters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to split a string based on 2 delimiters

```
let text = "How are you doing AND today OR yesterday?";
const myArray = text.split('AND|OR');
console.log(myArray)
```

But the above does not work
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a regular expression with an alternative.

```js
let text = "How are you doing AND today OR yesterday?";
const myArray = text.split(/AND|OR/);
console.log(myArray)
```